# facebook app generates an error code '100' when I run it on android device

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to run a facebook app on my android device. The app is a simple post button. In the emulator it runs ok, but in the device the following message was captured in the debug mode (eclipse).

```
error message: {"error":{"message":"(#100) Missing message or attachment","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

someone knows what going wrong?
thx!

the code of my activity is below

```
package f.b;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;

public class NewFaceAppActivity extends Activity {
        private final String id = "";//my id here
    private final String [] permissoes = {"publish_stream"};
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook(id);
    String access_token = "";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    login();
}

public void login(){

    /*
     * Get existing access_token if any
     */
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
    /*
     * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
     */
    if(facebook.isSessionValid() == false) {

        facebook.authorize(this, permissoes, -1, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {    
    super.onResume();
    facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
}

public void logout(){
    mAsyncRunner.logout(getBaseContext(), new RequestListener() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}

        });
}

public void postar(View v){
    //if(facebook.isSessionValid()){
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        String msg = et.getText().toString();
        String r = "";
        parameters.putString(this.access_token, msg );
        try {
            r = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, r, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //}else{login();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how this works in the emulator, you simply did not put the *message* parameter name into the bundle.

As you can see in the documentation for the [Post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), the name of the parameter is *"message"* and you inserted the message parameter with the access token as name.
It should be:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
String msg = et.getText().toString();
parameters.putString("message", msg);
```

There's no need to add the access toke, the SDK does that for you.

Comment: I'm using the correct parameter ("message") now, but in the device I still can't get this method to work correctly.
thx

Comment: the error that appear now is the following:

    {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with the authentication. That message should not arise if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem. I my device, the facebook pre-instalation cause the failure. I tried in another device without facebook. I installed the facebook.apk available at facebook/developers and everything is fine now. Thanks for your help :)